# Email from python sending email id with Comma in between the email address

Tags: python-3.x, html-email

I am sending email from python using gmail. Email is coming without any problem. But, the email id is showing with comma.

For example :
If to_email = 'ayan@zzzz.com'
In the recipient mailbox it is showing as : 'a,y,n,z,c,o,m'

Where as from email is absolutely fine.
Please let me know the solution

Comment: I am not sure if anybody can help you if you do not show your code.